# How to return all json data to Google Sheets using IMPORTJSON function?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm using the `IMPORTJSON` function found here: https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/

And this is the call I'm making in Google Sheets to AlphaVantage a stock quote provider:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo","Time Series (Daily)")
```

This has a lot of data (dates, and for each date, the high, low, close, open, and volume), which can be seen in by putting using this link in a browser:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

When I look at the JSON content using `Logger.log(json)`, all that data is there, but the only thing that gets returned to the spreadsheet is the dates.

This seems to be an issue where `IMPORTJSON` is returning a top level array, but I want the arrays within that top level array as well. How can I get those to be returned to the spreadsheet via the call to `IMPORTJSON`? Or do I need to create another custom function that loops through the array of dates and creates an array of prices for each date?

Comment: Have you looked at the log in the script editor yet? Log the results of `temparray` to make sure all data is being remapped.

Comment: All the data is making it into tempArr. Here is log of tempArr    [18-05-23 12:59:01:657 EDT] Logging output too large. Truncating output.

[18-05-23 12:59:01:766 EDT] [[2018-05-23, {3. low=96.3200, 5. volume=7846787, 1. open=96.7100, 2. high=97.8200, 4. close=97.7900}], [2018-05-22, {3. low=97.2000, 5. volume=15438935, 1. open=97.6800, 2. high=98.1700, 4. close=97.5000}]  And so on.

Comment: Looking at tempArr in debugging mode, it shows tempArr[100] for the 100 dates fetched. Each element of that 100 element array contains 2 elements - first element is a string representing the date, and the second element is an object containing 5 strings which represent the various prices.

Comment: OK, I think I understand this better. To access the first array in tempArr, and then the object inside that array (which is the second element), I can use `code`tempArr[0][1]`code`. And to get the key representing the closing price, I can use `code`tempArr[0][1]["4. close"]`code`.